# PageReference not redirecting to the desired page

Tags: visualforce, pagereference

I have a commandLink in a table that calls a method in the apex controller when clicked. I want it to open the page that has been assigned in the pageReference but instead its loading the same page and when I hover over the href is not showing the right page I have tried couple of different approach but none of them works.

the below VF code is residing on the Main.vfc and when the user clicks on the hyperlink I want the user to redirect to NewEmployee.vfc page.

```
<apex:commandLink value="{!e.Name}" action="{!clickOnName}">
     <apex:param name="eId"
     value="{!e.Id}"
     assignTo="{!empId}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
```

Controller:

```
public Id empId{get; set;}

public PageReference clickOnName() 
{
    system.debug('clickOnName//'  );
    //PageReference newPage = new PageReference('/' + Page.NewEmployee);//this did not work as well.
    PageReference newPage = Page.NewEmployee; 
    newPage.getParameters().put('empId', empId);  
    return newPage.setRedirect(true); 
}
```

Also I do not see the debug message when I click on the hyperlink meaning that this action method never calls that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you should not use `Apex` at all here.

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Page.NewEmployee, null, [empId=e.Id])}">
    e.Name
</apex:outputLink>
```

If you want to add more parameters, you can add them in between the square brackets.

```
[empId=e.Id,id=URLENCODE($CurrentPage.Parameters.Id)]
```

Comment: how can you get the url id along with the redirect if I go with the above code?

Comment: What do you mean by *url id*?

Comment: what I meant is that, when I'm on the main page I already have Id as a parameter in the url so when I redirect to a different page I want to pass that Id as well so in my case I will have `NewEmployee?id=xxxx&empId=xxxxx`

Comment: Then just add it to the parameters in between the square brackets.

Comment: Thanks Adrian 1+ just you know it should be `Parameters` ?

Comment: I'm curious to know why my code does not work the way I wanted?